# Dialog DateTextBox returns empty value

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog

I'm using DateTextBox in a Dialog, and I was surprised to see that after selecting a date, the dialog returns an empty value once submitted.
Even more surprising is the fact that it's broken in the Dojo demos themselves:
http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dijit_Dialog_Basic - enter a date, click OK, and see the returned value for the date.

Am I missing something? Any ideas how to get the right value from the dialog?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the demo is bogus.  The value attribute of the widget in Javascript is a Date object, which cannot be serialized with dojo.toJson.

```
dojo.toJson(new Date())
"{}"
```

How are you inspecting the return value?  If submitting an HTML form, two values should be submitted - one with the NAME attribute matching your declared DateTextBox element which should have an RFC3339-ish date, and another which represents the visual field but is not serialized with the given NAME attribute.